# Call REST Request inside XSLT and copy only some elements

Tags: xml, rest, xslt

I am attempting to make a REST call inside my XSL that will incorporate only parts of the response into the original transformed XML doc. I found one example that talked about using variables and the `document()` function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the original XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublishPELTEST xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
creationDateTime="2018-02-08T09:15:08-05:00" transLanguage="EN" 
baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1518099308834189587" maximoVersion="7 5 2 12" 
event="0">
  <PELTESTSet>
    <WORKORDER>
      <DESCRIPTION>My Workorder Description</DESCRIPTION>
      <WONUM>MWO-522</WONUM>
      <WOPRIORITY>3</WOPRIORITY>
      <WORKORDERID>2255202</WORKORDERID>
      <ASSIGNMENT>
        <LABORCODE>006325</LABORCODE>
      </ASSIGNMENT>
      <KUBROUNDENTRY>
        <KUBROUNDENTRYID>267433</KUBROUNDENTRYID>
        <LINEID>254735</LINEID>
        <OBSERVATION />
        <KUBROUNDLINE>
          <ASSETNUM>385691</ASSETNUM>
          <METERNAME>VLOPSTAT</METERNAME>
          <SEQUENCE>90</SEQUENCE>
          <ASSET>
            <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
            <DESCRIPTION>Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
            <SERVICEADDRESS>
              <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kingston Pike</STREETADDRESS>
            </SERVICEADDRESS>
          </ASSET>
          <METER>
            <DOMAINID>VLOPSTAT</DOMAINID>
            <METERNAME>VLOPSTAT</METERNAME>
          </METER>
        </KUBROUNDLINE>
      </KUBROUNDENTRY>
      <KUBROUNDENTRY>
        <KUBROUNDENTRYID>267432</KUBROUNDENTRYID>
        <LINEID>254734</LINEID>
        <OBSERVATION />
        <KUBROUNDLINE>
          <ASSETNUM>385691</ASSETNUM>
          <METERNAME>GLEAKGRD</METERNAME>
          <SEQUENCE>80</SEQUENCE>
          <ASSET>
            <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
            <DESCRIPTION>Asset2 Description</DESCRIPTION>
            <SERVICEADDRESS>
              <STREETADDRESS>2345 Kingston Pike</STREETADDRESS>
            </SERVICEADDRESS>
          </ASSET>
          <METER>
            <DOMAINID>CASEGRDE</DOMAINID>
            <METERNAME>GLEAKGRD</METERNAME>
          </METER>
        </KUBROUNDLINE>
      </KUBROUNDENTRY>
    </WORKORDER>
  </PELTESTSet>
</PublishPELTEST>
```

This is the REST request and the result that is returned normally:
    http://server.loc.org/maxrest/rest/mbo/alndomain/?domainid='SKIPRSN'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALNDOMAINMboSet rsStart="0" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ALNDOMAIN xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DOMAINID>KUBSKIPRSN</DOMAINID>
        <VALUE>TRAFFIC</VALUE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Traffic Control Needed</DESCRIPTION>
        <ALNDOMAINID>4906</ALNDOMAINID>
        <VALUEID>KUBSKIPRSN|TRAFFIC</VALUEID>
    </ALNDOMAIN>
    <ALNDOMAIN xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DOMAINID>KUBSKIPRSN</DOMAINID>
        <VALUE>NOT FOUND</VALUE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Asset Not Found</DESCRIPTION>
        <ALNDOMAINID>4006</ALNDOMAINID>
        <VALUEID>KUBSKIPRSN|NOT FOUND</VALUEID>
    </ALNDOMAIN>
    <ALNDOMAIN xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DOMAINID>KUBSKIPRSN</DOMAINID>
        <VALUE>SKIP ALL</VALUE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Skip All</DESCRIPTION>
        <ALNDOMAINID>3802</ALNDOMAINID>
        <VALUEID>KUBSKIPRSN|SKIP ALL</VALUEID>
    </ALNDOMAIN>
</ALNDOMAINMboSet>
```

What I had read previously about this was that you had to add the namespace to your xsl.  In this case, I believe the namespace is the same namespace as my origianl XML document.  So, I guessed that no other references were necessary.??

With that assumption, I ran the XSL below and it does not pull back any information related to the REST request.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="mea"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <yyy:createJob xmlns:yyy="http://place.org/mmm/app">
        <job>
          <id />
          <origin>AMS</origin>
          <metaId>
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant::mea:WORKORDERID" />
          </metaId>
          <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant::mea:DESCRIPTION" />
          </title>
          <dispatchGroup>FWSAMS</dispatchGroup>
          <priority>
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant::mea:WOPRIORITY" />
          </priority>
          <assignedTo>
            <xsl:value-of 
                select="descendant::mea:ASSIGNMENT/mea:LABORCODE" />
          </assignedTo>
          <jobDocument>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
              <root>
                <workorderNum>
                  <xsl:value-of select="descendant::mea:WONUM" />
                </workorderNum>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
                      select="descendant::mea:KUBROUNDENTRY" />
                <skipReasonDomain>
                  <xsl:variable name="myDomain">
                    <xsl:text>SKIPRSN</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:value-of 
 select="document(concat('http://server.loc.org/maxrest/rest/mbo/alndomain/?
 domainid=',$myDomain))/descendant::VALUE"/>
                </skipReasonDomain>
              </root>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </jobDocument>
            <completionDocument />
          </job>
        </yyy:createJob>
      </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy" />
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()|comment()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the resulting XML document:

```
<yyy:createJob
xmlns:yyy="http://place.org/mmm/app">
<job>
    <id></id>
    <origin>AMS</origin>
    <metaId>2255202</metaId>
    <title>My Workorder Description</title>
    <dispatchGroup>FWSAMS</dispatchGroup>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <assignedTo>006325</assignedTo>
    <jobDocument>
        <![CDATA[<root><workorderNum>MWO-522</workorderNum><KUBROUNDENTRY><KUBROUNDENTRYID>267433</KUBROUNDENTRYID><LINEID>254735</LINEID><OBSERVATION/><KUBROUNDLINE><ASSETNUM>385691</ASSETNUM><METERNAME>VLOPSTAT</METERNAME><SEQUENCE>90</SEQUENCE><ASSET><ASSETID>388391</ASSETID><DESCRIPTION>Asset Description</DESCRIPTION><SERVICEADDRESS><STREETADDRESS>1234 Kingston Pike</STREETADDRESS></SERVICEADDRESS></ASSET><METER><DOMAINID>VLOPSTAT</DOMAINID><METERNAME>VLOPSTAT</METERNAME></METER></KUBROUNDLINE></KUBROUNDENTRY><KUBROUNDENTRY><KUBROUNDENTRYID>267432</KUBROUNDENTRYID><LINEID>254734</LINEID><OBSERVATION/><KUBROUNDLINE><ASSETNUM>385691</ASSETNUM><METERNAME>GLEAKGRD</METERNAME><SEQUENCE>80</SEQUENCE><ASSET><ASSETID>388391</ASSETID><DESCRIPTION>Asset2 Description</DESCRIPTION><SERVICEADDRESS><STREETADDRESS>2345 Kingston Pike</STREETADDRESS></SERVICEADDRESS></ASSET><METER><DOMAINID>CASEGRDE</DOMAINID><METERNAME>GLEAKGRD</METERNAME></METER></KUBROUNDLINE></KUBROUNDENTRY><skipReasonDomain/></root>]]>
    </jobDocument>
    <completionDocument></completionDocument>
</job>
</yyy:createJob>
```

My desired output would be:

```
<yyy:createJob
xmlns:yyy="http://place.org/mmm/app">
<job>
    <id></id>
    <origin>AMS</origin>
    <metaId>2255202</metaId>
    <title>My Workorder Description</title>
    <dispatchGroup>FWSAMS</dispatchGroup>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <assignedTo>006325</assignedTo>
    <jobDocument>
        <![CDATA[<root><workorderNum>MWO-522</workorderNum><KUBROUNDENTRY><KUBROUNDENTRYID>267433</KUBROUNDENTRYID><LINEID>254735</LINEID><OBSERVATION/><KUBROUNDLINE><ASSETNUM>385691</ASSETNUM><METERNAME>VLOPSTAT</METERNAME><SEQUENCE>90</SEQUENCE><ASSET><ASSETID>388391</ASSETID><DESCRIPTION>Asset Description</DESCRIPTION><SERVICEADDRESS><STREETADDRESS>1234 Kingston Pike</STREETADDRESS></SERVICEADDRESS></ASSET><METER><DOMAINID>VLOPSTAT</DOMAINID><METERNAME>VLOPSTAT</METERNAME></METER></KUBROUNDLINE></KUBROUNDENTRY><KUBROUNDENTRY><KUBROUNDENTRYID>267432</KUBROUNDENTRYID><LINEID>254734</LINEID><OBSERVATION/><KUBROUNDLINE><ASSETNUM>385691</ASSETNUM><METERNAME>GLEAKGRD</METERNAME><SEQUENCE>80</SEQUENCE><ASSET><ASSETID>388391</ASSETID><DESCRIPTION>Asset2 Description</DESCRIPTION><SERVICEADDRESS><STREETADDRESS>2345 Kingston Pike</STREETADDRESS></SERVICEADDRESS></ASSET><METER><DOMAINID>CASEGRDE</DOMAINID><METERNAME>GLEAKGRD</METERNAME></METER></KUBROUNDLINE></KUBROUNDENTRY><skipReasonDomain><VALUE>TRAFFIC</VALUE><VALUE>NOT FOUND</VALUE><VALUE>SKIP ALL</VALUE></root>]]>
    </jobDocument>
    <completionDocument></completionDocument>
</job>
</yyy:createJob>
```

I know this is a lot of information, but I hope it helps someone to understand what I am trying to do and how I might be able to get there.  Any information is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample data that you provided of the XML that should be returned, the elements are bound to the namespace `http://www.ibm.com/maximo`.

However, you are selecting `descendant::VALUE`, which looks for `VALUE` elements bound to no namespace and therefore selects nothing.

You have that namespace declared in your stylesheet with the `mea` prefix, so it should be:

```
<xsl:value-of 
  select="document(concat('http://server.loc.org/maxrest/rest/mbo/alndomain/?domainid=',
    $myDomain))/descendant::mea:VALUE"/>
```

Comment: I added the mea namespace reference and still get nothing.

Comment: I can’t access that URL, so it is hard to troubleshoot. Try using xsl:copy-of without an XPath to verify that you are getting the response you think you are.

Comment: Still no luck.  I removed the XPath and used copy-of.

Comment: Hmm, what XSLT engine are you using? Does the current URL require any authentication or perform any redirects? You are sure that the response is well-formed XML? Maybe try requesting a different XML from a public URL.

Comment: I believe the XSLT engine is 1.0.  The URL does not perform any redirects, and doesn't seem to require any authentication.  It is well-formed.  I will try a public URL and see what happens.